# DictVectorizer throws a ValueError: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am trying to use DictVectorizer for a classification job. This is the first time I'm using this.

My dictionary looks like this

```
students = 
[{'courses': [], 'state': 'CA', 'textbook': [9704873, 11067976], 'zip': 104},
 {'courses': ['HIST 2'], 'state': 'CA', 'textbook': [7072542], 'zip': 104}, 
 {'courses': ['BIOSC 4'], 'state': 'CA', 'textbook': [4359080, 13320], 'zip': 110}]

from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
vec = DictVectorizer()
array = vec.fit_transform(students).toarray()
```

When I'm trying to put it into DictVectorizer, it is throwing me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/aanam/PycharmProjects/predict_school/scikit_test.py", line 36, in <module>
    array = vec.fit_transform(students).toarray()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 142, in fit_transform
    return self.transform(X)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\dict_vectorizer.py", line 230, in transform
    values.append(dtype(v))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: HIST 2
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i vectorize list using sklearn DictVectorizer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24250469/how-can-i-vectorize-list-using-sklearn-dictvectorizer)