# Preparing variable-length data for sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

Since this is a complicated problem (at least for me), I will try to keep this as brief as possible.

My data is of the form

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# edit: a1 and a2 are linked as they are part of the same object
a1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10]])
a2 = np.array([[5, 6, 5], [2, 3], [3, 4, 8, 1]])

b = np.array([6, 15, 24])
y = np.array([0, 1, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a1=a1.tolist(),a2=a2.tolist(), b=b, y=y))  


                  a1            a2   b  y
0      [1, 2, 3]     [5, 6, 5]   6  0
1         [4, 5]        [2, 3]  15  1
2  [7, 8, 9, 10]  [3, 4, 8, 1]  24  1
```

which I would like to use in sklearn for classification, e.g.

```
from sklearn import tree
X = df[['a1', 'a2', 'b']]
Y = df['y']
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
print(clf.predict([[2., 2.]]))
```

However, while pandas can handle lists as entries, sklearn, by design,  cannot. In this example the `clf.fit` will result in `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` to which you can find plenty of answers.

---

**But how do you deal with such data?**

I tried to split the data up into multiple columns (i.e. `a1[0] ... a1[3]` - code for that is a bit lengthy), but `a1[3]` will be empty (`NaN`, `0` or whatever invalid value you think of). Imputation does not make sense here, since no value is supposed to be there.

Of course, such a procedure has an impact on the result of the classification as the algorithm might pick up the "zero" value as something *meaningful*.

---

If the dataset is large enough, so I thought, it might be worth splitting it up in equal lengths of `a1`. But this procedure can reduce the power of the classification algorithm, since the length of `a1` might help to distinguish between classes.

I also thought of using `warm start` for algorithms that support (e.g. [Perceptron](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron.html#sklearn.linear_model.Perceptron)) and fit it to data split by the length of `a1`. But this would surely fail, would it not? The datasets would have different number of features, so I assume that something would go wrong.

---

Solutions to this problem surely must exist and I've simply not found the right place in the documentation.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, one thing you could do is prepare your data like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791719/dictvectorizer-for-list-as-one-feature-in-python-pandas-and-scikit-learn/40929783#40929783 (DictVectorizer can be very useful in this kind of situations I believe..)

Comment: +1 for DictVectorizer @mkaran. Additionally you can use some central tendencies of your list feature, like **length, mean, median** etc. or more complex techniques like [Kernel Approximation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/kernel_approximation.html#kernel-approximation) or PCA or something like One-hot encoding to transform your feature into another dimensions. You need to try different approaches to see what works best for you.

Comment: Is the order of the elements in `a` significant?  That is, is `a` a sequence, or is it just a collection?  If you want to preserve the ordering, you'll need to be careful with DictVectorizer, and I also guess that MultiLabelBinarizer won't work very well.

Comment: The ordering of `a` is indeed significant. The real problem includes variables `a1`, `a2`, `a3` etc which are projections of objects into the data frame. As such the first item in `a1` is "bundled" with the first item in `a2`.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify: order needs to be preserved. I could try to use PCA, but I would have to do it for all `a*` columns, so even more information will be lost.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume for a second those numbers are numerical categories.
What you can do is transform column 'a' into a set of binary columns, of which each corresponds to a possible value of 'a'.

Taking your example code, we would:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10]])
b = np.array([6, 15, 24])
y = np.array([0, 1, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=a.tolist(),b=b,y=y))

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
MLB = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(MLB.fit_transform(df['a']), columns=MLB.classes_)
df_2

    1   2   3   4   5   7   8   9   10
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

Than, we can just concat the old and new data:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df_2, df.drop('a',1)],1)

    1   2   3   4   5   7   8   9   10  b   y
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   0
1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   15  1
2   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   24  1
```

Please do notice that if you have a training and a test set, it would be wise to first concat em, do the transform, and than separate 'em. Thats because one of the data sets can contain terms that do not belong to the other.

Hope that helps

Edit:

If you are worried that might make your df too big, its perfectly okay to apply PCA to the binarized variables. It will reduce cardinality while maintaining an arbitrary amount of variance/correlation.

Comment: Hi @epattaro, thank you for your solution.
Unfortunately, `a` is not a category. I should have explained better.
In the real example, `a` is a part of an object which is spread across several columns:

    a1 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10]])
    a2 = np.array([[5, 6, 5], [2, 3], [3, 4, 8, 1]])
    
    b = np.array([6, 15, 24])
    y = np.array([0, 1, 1])

    df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a1=a1.tolist(),a2=a2.tolist(), b=b, y=y))

Answer (score 1):

Sklearn likes the data in 2d array i.e. shape (batch_size, features) 
The simplest solution is to prepare one feature vector by concatenating the arrays using numpy.concatenate. The pass this feature vector to sklearn. Since the length of each column is fixed this should work.

Comment: I agree with the idea, however, I would use `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/sequence/pad_sequences), It should be slightly less work