# While using machine learning algorithm using scikit-learn is it possible to have a single feature as a list?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

By this what I mean is if I can have a feature list as below

[ 1,2,4,[1,5,8],9 ]

where a single feature is again a list or a numpy array.

Comment: You need to one-hot encode the features. Look at [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and [MultilabelBinarizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html)

Comment: Maybe take a look at [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791719/dictvectorizer-for-list-as-one-feature-in-python-pandas-and-scikit-learn/40929783#40929783 in order to encode your list values