# Python3 Sklearn Prediction Error Value Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have written a program to try and predict if a match will be won or lost against two other players based off of a dataset of wins and loses, but when I execute the code I get an error saying,

```
classifier = classifier.fit(features,labels)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence,".
```

My code:

```
#code to predict if game will be won in rocket league...
#Recipe Collect Data->Train Classifier-Predict
from sklearn import tree
#Contains Team Ranks and Enemy Ranks
'''
1: Rookie
2: Semipro
3:Pro
4:Veteran
5:Expert
6:Master
7:Legend
8:Rocketeer
'''
#First Array Set is Team Second Enemy
#Doubles Stats
features = [
    [1,[8,4]],
    [3,[5,5]],
    [3,[4,4]]
]
#games won/lost
# 0 for lose 1 for win
labels = [0,0,1]
classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
#Learning Algorithm finds paterns
classifier = classifier.fit(features,labels)
print(classifier.predict([
    [[2],[4,3]]
]))
```

What can I do to fix this???

Comment: List of a list is not supported. Your second feature is a list. You should preprocess it to make your training array dimensions consistent

Comment: Also describe more about your data `features`

Comment: Take a look at [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html) and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32791719/dictvectorizer-for-list-as-one-feature-in-python-pandas-and-scikit-learn/40929783#40929783 for ideas about encoding your list values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you use a sequence as a single feature. 
Currently your data has two feature for each row (`[1,[8,4]]`). The first is an integer (`1`) and the second is a sequence with two integers (`[8,4]`).
I'm not sure what each feature represents however all features should be numeric.

A simple fix could be turning the sequence into two features:

```
features = [
    [1,8,4],
    [3,5,5],
    [3,4,4]
]
#games won/lost
# 0 for lose 1 for win
labels = [0,0,1]
classifier = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
#Learning Algorithm finds paterns
classifier = classifier.fit(features,labels)
print(classifier.predict([2,4,3]))
```

The output of this code is:

```
[1]
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: Glad I could help. If the answer helped please accept it.